# htaccess - Force SSL and www with Domain in Subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I'm using a cPanel host, which, unfortunately, does not allow me access to Apache conf files in order to set up any `VirtualHosts`. I have my domain in a subfolder. I'm now also trying to force SSL as well as forcing `www`.

My requirements:

- Domain needs to be in a subfolder, since I also have other domains
- Force SSL
- Force www. in the URL

The following is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```

I've made various attempts that seem to get me one or two of my requirements, but not all of them at the same time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Nic3500 I did research. I've searched around for this issue, but was unable to find a solution that fits my exact requirements. Most solutions handle two, but not all three.

Comment: The subdirectory should be handled on the Apache server side, with `alias` or separate `VirtualHost` for your domains.  Forcing the user into a directory at the browser level is not required IMHO.

Comment: I agree, however, It's a cPanel host, which I find quite limiting. From what I've seen, I'm unable to do a `VirtualHost` with any cPanel setup that I've worked with, which I find very frustrating. If I could, I would totally do separate VirtualHosts for each domain and subdomain.

Comment: ah, to be honest, I never use cpanel, always directly in the conf, I will remove the -1.

Comment: Thanks! I work in conf whenever I can as well.

Comment: Can you show your attempts to force SSL and www?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost there. After, the second line, I had to add a couple of `RewriteConds`. Not on HTTPS or, not on www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

The final set of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
RewriteRule ^$ /subfolder/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Tested, and it forces SSL, and WWW in the domain, and keeps everything in the subfolder.